# How to display row group and grand total percentages on a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2017

[image]

I have an SSRS matrix report that i have so far managed to format as above. As you can see i have managed to add the totals by "Area" broken down by "Section"

I have also added the grand total row at the very bottom and all is fine up-to this point.

Now my questions:

1. How can i add the percentage contribution of each "Section" towards the total percentage (100%). See the red row in the screenshot below, in this case that's what i want to add.
2. How can i add the percentage contribution of each "Area" towards the total percentage. See the "Total (%) by Area" column in red in the below screenshot.

Does any body have an idea of how i can achieve the above.

I want the final matrix to look like the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to do a calculation for a group in a table, you can use an aggregate expression with the scope of the Group Name.

So you would use the Group Name that is creating the Section and Area groups.

```
=SUM(Fields!COUNT_FIELD.Value) / SUM(Fields!COUNT_FIELD.Value, "SECTION")


=SUM(Fields!COUNT_FIELD.Value) / SUM(Fields!COUNT_FIELD.Value, "AREA")
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because it gave me good direction that led me to finding a solution.